# Image not showing R dashboard

Tags: r, image, shinydashboard

My code :

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),

 dashboardSidebar(),

 dashboardBody(img(src = "image.png")))

server <- function(input, output,session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My path : `Cloud / project / www / image.png`

My image is just showing like that :

[image]

I wonder if it's because I'm in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay resolved, I don't really understand because I already tried the "Run app" and nothing happened but now it's working. 
It's just that sometimes when I do Ctrl + A and Ctrl + Enter, the png image doesn't show.